# Problem with Columns of SQL table on PHP FPDF

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, fpdf

I've been having trouble creating a PDF using FPDF with PHP. I managed to fetch the data from my database and make the headers get right, but when the data gets posted it gets all chaotic, the script first puts all results from one column before starting the rest, making the positioning get really wrong.

I am using php 7

Here is one example of how data is being shown:

[Column Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OyQe.png)

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SAAJ.png)
I can't understand why the first column is shown with the right Y position but all the other ones get like this
Here is the code as is.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `tb_login`");
$number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

//Inicializar as colunas
$column_idlogin = "";
$column_iduser = "";
$column_nome = "";
$column_snome = "";
$column_cpf = "";
$column_email = "";
$column_datahr = "";


//Adicionar a coluna para cada linha presente
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $idlogin = $row["idLogin"];
    $iduser =  $row["idUsuario"];
    $nome =  $row["nmUsuario"];
    $snome =  $row["sobrenomeUsuario"];
    $cpf =  $row["cpfUsuario"];
    $email =  $row["emailUsuario"];
    $datahr =  $row["data_hora"];


    $column_idlogin = $column_idlogin.$idlogin."\n";
    $column_iduser = $column_iduser.$iduser."\n";
    $column_nome = $column_nome.$nome."\n";
    $column_snome = $column_snome.$snome."\n";
    $column_cpf = $column_cpf.$cpf."\n";
    $column_email = $column_email.$email."\n";
    $column_datahr = $column_datahr.$datahr."\n";


}

$mysqli -> close();

//Create a new PDF file
$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

//Fields Name position
$Y_Fields_Name_position = 12;
//Table position, under Fields Name
$Y_Table_Position = 24;

//First create each Field Name
//Gray color filling each Field Name box
$pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
//Bold Font for Field Name
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Fields_Name_position);
$pdf->SetX(20);
$pdf->Cell(18,12,'ID_LOGIN',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->SetX(38);
$pdf->Cell(18,12,'ID_USER',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->SetX(56);
$pdf->Cell(20,12,'NOME',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->SetX(76);
$pdf->Cell(28,12,'SOBRENOME',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->SetX(104);
$pdf->Cell(30,12,'CPF',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->SetX(134);
$pdf->Cell(30,12,'EMAIL',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->SetX(164);
$pdf->Cell(34,12,'DATA_ACESSO',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Ln();

//Agora mostre as colunas
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);

$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
$pdf->SetX(20);
$pdf->MultiCell(18,12,$column_idlogin,1);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
$pdf->SetX(38);
$pdf->MultiCell(18,12,$column_iduser,1);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
$pdf->SetX(56);
$pdf->MultiCell(20,12,$column_nome,1);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
$pdf->SetX(76);
$pdf->MultiCell(28,12,$column_snome,1);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
$pdf->SetX(104);
$pdf->MultiCell(30,12,$column_cpf,1);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
$pdf->SetX(134);
$pdf->MultiCell(30,12,$column_email,1);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
$pdf->SetX(164);
$pdf->MultiCell(34,12,$column_datahr,1);



$pdf->Output()
```

I tried declaring Sety as $Y_Table_Position for each column, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: you try to make short cuts, that are not working, add a new row in the pdf when you process the mysql resultset as a function.

Answer (score 0):

I never used this library and didn't test this code so take it with a grain of salt.

I used your one cell working example and tried to iterate on it.

I cleaned up a bit of your code.

That while loop was strange.

```
//Create a new PDF file
$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

//First create each Field Name
//Gray color filling each Field Name box
$pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
//Bold Font for Field Name
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->SetY(12);
$pdf->SetX(20);
$pdf->Cell(18,12,'ID_LOGIN',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->SetX(38);
$pdf->Cell(18,12,'ID_USER',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->SetX(56);
$pdf->Cell(20,12,'NOME',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->SetX(76);
$pdf->Cell(28,12,'SOBRENOME',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->SetX(104);
$pdf->Cell(30,12,'CPF',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->SetX(134);
$pdf->Cell(30,12,'EMAIL',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->SetX(164);
$pdf->Cell(34,12,'DATA_ACESSO',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Ln();

//Agora mostre as colunas
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `tb_login`");
$number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
//Lets just create array of rows first
$rows = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
/**
 * Custom cell width config 
 */
$cells_config_arr = [
    'idLogin'          => ['x' => 20],
    'idUsuario'        => ['x' => 20],
    'nmUsuario'        => ['x' => 20],
    'sobrenomeUsuario' => ['x' => 20],
    'cpfUsuario'       => ['x' => 20],
    'emailUsuario'     => ['x' => 20],
    'data_hora'        => ['x' => 20]
];
$cell_y = 24;
foreach($rows as $row){
    $cell_x = 0;
    foreach($row as $key => $value){
        //Lets set coord of by with of last cells sumed
        $cell_x = $cell_x + $cells_config_arr[ $key ]['x'];
        $pdf->SetY($cell_y);
        $pdf->SetX($cell_x);
        $pdf->Cell($cells_config_arr[ $key ]['x'], 12, $value, 1, 0, 'L', 1);
    }
    $pdf->Ln();
    $cell_y = $cell_y + $cell_y;
}
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: Greetings Matas! Thanks for such quick reply. Your code is clear and helped me a lot! I still haven't found my answer, but I feel a bit closer with the information you provided me. I think that this library does not suport the  $pdf->Cell($cells_config_arr[ $key ]['x'], 12, $value, 1, 0, 'L', 1); Line, as it is not displaying the rows and cells, but I will use your creation as basis to develop a solution. Thanks a bunch! As soon as I nail it I will edit with my answer